# Analyzing memory growth due to C++ objects in a java process

Tags: c++, heap-memory

My java application calls C++ code using JNI calls. I want to check the program for memory leaks in the C++ code. Tools like jconsole are only for analyzing java objects heap. What can I do?

Comment: What is your compiler and OS?

Comment: Windows Server 2003. C++ code is visual studio programs.

Comment: Are you asking about memory leaks in your C++ code in general, or JNI objects in the heap specifically?

Comment: My C++ code is called only from a JVM via JNI calls. So I'm asking about JNI objects in the heap specifically.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite native heap leak detection tool for Windows is [umdh.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343).  However, this will also display the current Java GC heap memory footprint, in whatever native form the JVM uses.

You should still be able to identify memory attributable to your C++ code since it will (provided symbols are set up properly according to the UMDH instructions) have a callstack matching C++ code.  So having Java code coresident will muddy the waters but should not make it impossible to track C++/native memory usage.

Comment: Can you tell how I use it for JNI application? Run the tool on java.exe itself?

Comment: My understanding is that the C++ code you call will run in the same process within `java.exe`, in which case its heap usage can be tracked this way.  if you are lucky the JVM will use a different native heap in which to manage GC memory, making identifying C++ usage straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You need a native heap debugging tool. There are many available depending on your platform and what compiler was used for the native component.